# SIGALRM signal not getting generated. In my code the function NAKTime is not getting called

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


const struct itimerval nak_timer={{20,10} , {20,10} };
struct itimerval old_value = {{10,0},{10,0}};
sigset_t set;

int main()
{

    int rc , i=0;
    void NAKTime(int signal);
    //Register a signal handler
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set,SIGALRM);
    sigset(SIGALRM , NAKTime);
    //Create a Timer
    rc = setitimer(ITIMER_REAL , &nak_timer,&old_value);
    if(1 == rc)
    {
        printf("\nError in execution of Timer \n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Timer function executed\n");
    return 0;
}

void NAKTime(int signal)
{
    printf("Entered NAKTime Function()\n");
    if(signal == SIGALRM)
        printf("\nFunction NAKTime Called!!\n");
}
```

On execution of the setitimer(...) the NAKTime function must get called. But it is not getting called. I tried test NAKTime with other signals like SIGINT and it worked perfectly fine. I am not sure if I am missing something on setitimer() function.

Comment: OT: Do not use `printf()` in signal handers, as it isn't guaranteed to be async-signal-safe.

Comment: But it works with SIGINT signal

Comment: Your prototype for the NakTime() function  is buried within the main() function, so is not seen at the declaration of the NakTime() function.

Comment: according to: <http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html>, Function: int setitimer (int which, const struct itimerval *new, struct itimerval *old) ...

    The return value is 0 on success and -1 on failure.  

    so the check for '1' is not correct

Answer (score 2):

You have set an alarm... but your program is exiting before the alarm goes off...

Put a "sleep(60)"  as follows:

```
printf("Timer function executed\n");
sleep(60);
printf("After sleep\n");
return 0;`
```

You should now see it works.